# How does this print the whole array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference

So I was messing around with vectors and the windows-api and someone suggested that I use a pointer to the first element in the vector as a buffer for a function.

I went out and tried printing the array with the syntax and it printed the whole array and now I wonder why is that?

```cpp
char test[10] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j' };
std::cout << &test[0] << std::endl;
//output: abcdefghij
```

Edit 1:
I found out that printing with the array name worked too, but this code suprised me becasue using the reference syntax it printed the char array in decreasing order. But without using the refrenece syntax it does not I wonder why is that?

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    std::cout << &test[0] + i << " ";
}
//outputs: abcdefghij bcdefghij cdefghij defghij efghij fghij ghij hij ij j
```

Comment: You're lucky you got just those items, as `std::cout` requires a null-terminated array of char, and you did not explicitly place a null entry at the end of that array.

Comment: " using the reference syntax" You are not using any reference syntax here. If you mean `&test[0]`, this is the address-of operator which creates a pointer from its operand and is equivalent to just `test` in this context.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Some might say OP was *un*lucky in that the test mislead him/her to an incorrect conclusion.

Comment: You are making use of the char* functionality of std::cout used to print c-strings. @PaulMcKenzie explained that since you don't null terminate it you could get more data than you expect. This is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&test[0]` is a pointer to a char, to the first character in an array.

Sending a `char *` to `cout` is the equivalent of printing a string.  The underlying logic will start dumping characters to the screen until it finds a NULL character, i.e. a `char` with a value of zero.

As others have mentioned, you are just lucky that you apparently had a zero (uninitialized memory?) immediately after the end of your array.  Otherwise, the string printer would have kept going until it found one.

Comment: Formally, passing a `char*` that doesn't point to null terminated array is undefined behavior. It *may* print the data and stop at the first `'\0'`, but it might do anything else due to the transformations compilers are allowed to do or due to how the OS handles memory accesses.